# Stopping windows service with taskkill

Tags: c#, windows, service, taskkill

I need help to kill a windows service using C#, now to kill the service use the following option:

From the cmd:

```
sc queryex ServiceName
```

After discovering the `PID` of the service

```
taskkill /pid 1234(exemple) /f
```

Comment: Do you have any C# code?  You could start a new process that executes a command...

Answer (score 5):

For ease of reading but I would separate the services interactions into it's own class with separate methods IsServiceInstalled, IsServiceRunning, StopService ..etc if you get what I mean.

Also by stopping the service it should kill the process already but I included how you would do something like that as well. If the service won't stop and you are stopping it by killing the process, I would look at the service code if you have access to it wasn't built correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceController sc = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName.Equals("MyServiceNameHere"));
            if (sc != null)
            {
                if (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))
                {
                    sc.Stop();

                    Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcessName");
                    if (procs.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Process proc in procs)
                        {
                            //do other stuff if you need to find out if this is the correct proc instance if you have more than one
                            proc.Kill();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to give it the up arrow and mark as answer. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcessName") cannot find my service on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Process.GetProcessesByName("service name") does not work in my case but the below does.
You will need references to System.ServiceProcess and to System.Management.

```
    public static void Kill()
    {
        int processId = GetProcessIdByServiceName(ServiceName);
     
        var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        process.Kill();
    }

    private static int GetProcessIdByServiceName(string serviceName)
    {

        string qry = $"SELECT PROCESSID FROM WIN32_SERVICE WHERE NAME = '{serviceName }'";
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(qry);
        var managementObjects = new ManagementObjectSearcher(qry).Get();

        if (managementObjects.Count != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"In attempt to kill a service '{serviceName}', expected to find one process for service but found {managementObjects.Count}.");

        int processId = 0;

        foreach (ManagementObject mngntObj in managementObjects)
            processId = (int)(uint) mngntObj["PROCESSID"];

        if (processId == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"In attempt to kill a service '{serviceName}', process ID for service is 0. Possible reason is the service is already stopped.");

        return processId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the process id use
Process.GetProcessById(Id).Kill();
If you know the process name use
Process.GetProcessesByName(name).Kill();

Comment: Both those methods return an array, so you cannot call a method on that.

Comment: Why not? Is possible to kill all process with this name. Example you have 5 window of Chrome and want kill all process of chrome. With this method Process.GetProcessesByName(name).Kill(); is possible to kill all.

Comment: @AntonNikolayevich, the code sample you provided will fail because the `Kill` method is available on the `Process` class and not the collection but you could do something like `Process.GetProcessesByName(name).ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());`

Answer (score 1):

Here the code uses 4 methods to stop your service including TaskKill, note that you must have sufficient privilege to do so.

```
  foreach (ServiceController Svc in ServiceController.GetServices())
    {
        using (Svc)
        {
            //The short name of "Microsoft Exchange Service Host"
            if (Svc.ServiceName.Equals("YourServiceName"))
            {
                if (Svc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    if (Svc.CanStop)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Svc.Stop();
                            Svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //Try to stop using Process
                            foreach (Process Prc in Process.GetProcessesByName(Svc.ServiceName))
                            {
                                using (Prc)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        //Try to kill the service process
                                        Prc.Kill();
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        //Try to terminate the service using taskkill command
                                        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                                        {
                                            FileName = "cmd.exe",
                                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                                            UseShellExecute = false,
                                            Arguments = string.Format("/c taskkill /pid {0} /f", Prc.Id)
                                        });

                                        //Additional:
                                        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                                        {
                                            FileName = "net.exe",
                                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                                            UseShellExecute = false,
                                            Arguments = string.Format("stop {0}", Prc.ProcessName)
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For me the line    Process Prc in Process.GetProcessesByName(Svc.ServiceName) does not seem able to find the process using the service name.

Comment: Cannot find process by name in my case. This was on Windows 7.