# sc queryex themes, taskkill /pid 1148 /f

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, taskkill

I want to know how to stop a hanging service with c# like i would do in cmd `using sc queryex servicename` to get the pid and `taskkill /pid pidnumber /f` to kill the hanging service...

I have read [Stopping windows service with taskkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014152/stopping-windows-service-with-taskkill) but this did not give me a solution.

I would like something like this:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("aServiceName").Kill();
```

Which isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Use *PsKill*. It is an exec utility produced by sysinternals.
You can use it in command line mode as well as in programatic mode.
Id you want to do that programmatically, I would recommand to create a utility class that has a method that takes a service id, creates a process, using the *Process* class in C#, attach the process to *pskill.exe*, passing the parameters to pskill and lauch the process with the start method. Here is a sample:

```
public static void KillProcess(int _servicePid)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\pstools\pskill.exe", _servicePid);
}
```

PsKill download link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx