# Correct way to kill service in C#, to be always recovered by SCM

Tags: c#, windows, service

We have a service that needs to kill itself (reason: we use a third party lib, that has unpredictable behavior in shutdown scenarios ...). Sometimes the service is not restarted by the Windows Service Control manager. The service recovery actions, in the SCM, are set to "Restart the Service" (for the first, the second and subsequent failures).

That's the way we kill our service:

```
public static void TerminateProcess(string message)
{
   Log.ErrorFormat("Terminating Process becauses of: {0}", message);

   Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

Does anybody knows if this `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` is a good way to kill the service?

I also read some threads, where the following combination was suggested:

```
class MyService : ServiceBase
{
   void KillMe()
   {
      this.ExitCode = 1; // ServiceBase.ExitCode
      System.Environment.Exit(1);
   }
}
```

I also found this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014152/stopping-windows-service-with-taskkill), but it doesn't state anything about service recovery.

What's the preferred/safe way to kill a service, so that the SCM will restart it?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Make a singleton instance of your service. And then you you can stop your service using stop() method.

```
public partial class ABCService : ServiceBase
{
    public static ABCService ServiceInstance;

    private void InitService()
    {
        ServiceInstance = this;
    }
}

    public static void StopService()
    {
        if(ABCService.ServiceInstance != null)
        {
            ABCService.ServiceInstance.Stop();
        }
    }
```

And you don't want the to restart automatically

```
    public static void ChangeServiceMode(bool serviceAutoEnable)
        {
            RegistryKey key     = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\NixService", true);

            if (key != null)
            {
                //Set service to manual / Automatic (Automatic = 2, manual = 3)
                int serviceMode = serviceAutoEnable ? 2 : 3;
                key.SetValue("Start", serviceMode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                key.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is necessary to understand: in what cases it is necessary to disable the service.
The first method you describe allows you to kill a service from a third-party code base. And the second option is in the service itself, but I think that the last option is not realizable, because the question arises: what circumstances should there be for the service to kill itself ???

IMHO the first option is more practical.